# My process being killed the moment it start training, tensorflow object detection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection

I am trying to train image detector using my own dataset but it fails. I've made few changes in configuration file apart from number of classes and paths. Here are they

```
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/data_train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/rdata_train.pbtxt"
  queue_capacity: 2
  min_after_dequeue: 1
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.1
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 0.000001
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  batch_queue_capacity: 5
  num_batch_queue_threads: 8
  prefetch_queue_capacity: 5
}
```

But it fails to start training. I checked issues on tensorflow research repository but no specific answer I was able to find. Here is the output from console.

```
/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /dev/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py:228: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py:736: Supervisor.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
2018-03-22 14:14:27.789420: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-03-22 14:14:27.925567: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-03-22 14:14:27.925895: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2018-03-22 14:14:27.925920: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-03-22 14:14:29.848609: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10764 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ckpts/model.ckpt-0
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path ckpts/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
Killed
```

Comment: Killed means it went out of memory, so there is not much else to say than the program requires more RAM than what was available at the time.

Comment: even with batch size 1 and GPU of 12GB it needs more!!! Kind a strange!!!

Comment: I am not talking about GPU RAM but system (CPU) RAM.

Comment: `batch_queue_capacity: 1
  num_batch_queue_threads: 2
  prefetch_queue_capacity: 1`

With reduced data and above changes it was able to run for 123 steps and then killed.

Comment: Can it be a case of memory leak?

Comment: How much RAM do you have and what are the characteristics of your dataset?

Comment: Right now I have reduced my dataset to just 20 images but resolutions are from 300 to 5000 pixels and I've 59 GB of RAM

Comment: Was facing the same issue, on my laptop but I was able to train the same **ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/model** model on more han 16000 images, using GCP (35GB RAM). The model was perfectly trained on all 23 categories my data set had, in 20000 steps, can you try mentioning `num_classes: x`, x is no of categories in your data set and also try reducing no of steps to 5K ~ 10K, you can increase if required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the CPU RAM that was out of memory. I train my network using GPU, but strangely, when I retrain it with load_weights, it killed.

Increase CPU RAM fixed my problem.

Comment: how do you increase the CPU RAM usage ?

Comment: I increase the memory dump size.

Comment: How can we do that?